# Ionic-Vue Ionicons 5.x.x doesn't show icon

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs2, ionicons, ionic-vue

I used ionic-vue with ionicons 5.0.1 but after call

```
<ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
```

i was following https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/build-your-first-ionic-vue-app-18kj and https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19078 tutorial, but stucked and icon in FAB cannot be show.
This is my syntax, thank you for helping.

```
<template>
   <ion-page>

        ....

        <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
            <ion-fab-button @click="$router.push({ name: 'new-item' })">
                <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
            </ion-fab-button>
        </ion-fab>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-page>
</template>

<script>

...

import { addIcons } from 'ionicons';
import * as allIcons from 'ionicons/icons';

const currentIcons = Object.keys(allIcons).map(i => {
  const key = i.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `-${letter.toLowerCase()}`)
  if(typeof allIcons[i] === 'string') {
    return {
      [key]: allIcons[i],
    }
  }
  return {
    ['ios-' + key]: allIcons[i].ios,
    ['md-' + key]: allIcons[i].md,
  };
});

const iconsObject = Object.assign({}, ...currentIcons);
addIcons(iconsObject);

...
</script>
```

Result FAB does not show icon 'add':

[image]

Comment: Did you already find a solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For Ionic Vue 3 using Composition API:

```html
<template>
  <ion-icon :icon="rocket" />
</template>

<script>
import { IonIcon } from '@ionic/vue';
import { rocket } from 'ionicons/icons';

export default {
  components: { IonIcon },
  setup() {
    return {
      rocket
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

For `<script setup>`

```html
<script setup>
import { IonIcon } from '@ionic/vue';
import { rocket } from 'ionicons/icons';
</script>

<template>
  <ion-icon :icon="rocket" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also following the same guide(https://dev.to/devmount/how-to-use-ionicons-v5-with-vue-js-53g2), and I encountered the same issue.

I decided to downgrade the ionicons version to version 4:

```
npm i ionicons@4
```

This solved my issue.

The code that I used from the guide:

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>

      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content padding>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-checkbox slot="start"></ion-checkbox>
          <ion-label>
            <h1>Create Ideaa</h1>
            <ion-note>Run Idea by Brandy</ion-note>
          </ion-label>
          <ion-badge color="success" slot="end">5 Days</ion-badge>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
        <ion-fab-button >
          <ion-icon name="add"  ></ion-icon>
        </ion-fab-button>
      </ion-fab>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

 <script>

  import { add } from "ionicons/icons";
  import { addIcons } from "ionicons";
  addIcons({
    "ios-add": add.ios,
    "md-add": add.md
  });

  export default {
    name: "HomePage",
    props: {
      msg: String
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Downgrading the `ionicons` version to `4.x.x` worked for me too!

Answer (score 3):

In your **main.js** file

```
import * as allIcons from "ionicons/icons";

Vue.mixin({
  data() {
    return {
      i: allIcons,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    icon(name) {
      return this.i[name];
    }
  }
});
```

now you can use `<ion-icon :src="icon('search')"></ion-icon>` anywhere in the vue application, it is going to work

Answer (score 2):

hey thanks for checking out the blogs and videos...

you can also get the icons this way...

```
<template>
<ion-button @click="handleAddItemClicked" >
  <ion-icon slot="icon-only" :src="i.saveOutline" ></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
      <ion-button @click="handleAddItemClicked" >
  <ion-icon slot="icon-only" :src="i.save" ></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
      <ion-button @click="handleAddItemClicked" >
  <ion-icon slot="icon-only" :src="i.saveSharp" ></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
</template>

<script>
import * as allIcons from "ionicons/icons";

...

  data() {
    return {
      i : allIcons,
    };
  },
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed this comment in a closed issue on `@modus/ionic-vue` repo: https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/ionic-vue/issues/120#issuecomment-633666592

```
import { addIcons } from 'ionicons'
import { add, cartOutline } from 'ionicons/icons'
addIcons({ add, "cart-outline": cartOutline })
```

This worked with `ionicons@5.1.2` installed. Note how the multi word icon imports are camel case instead of kebab case. If you want to use the kebab case variant of the name for an `ion-icon` you have to do the assignment to the kebab case name yourself like in the case of `cart-outline` above.

Though if you wanted to add all of them at once and support kebab case, you could map a new object like this:

```
import { addIcons } from 'ionicons'
import * as allIcons from 'ionicons/icons'
import _ from 'lodash'
addIcons(_.mapKeys(allIcons, (value, key) => _.kebabCase(key))
```

Answer (score 1):

After i tried everything, there weren't any errors reported anywehere, just icon wasn't there.

Please check twice, that you have **set the color of the icon**, because in default icon style color is inhereit.
So, if you have for example, a green button, the color of the icon will be also green, if you do not specify.